# How to show progress bar in getMapAsync?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have a progress bar and i want show it when getMapAsync.
However i don't where to put progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE).
With a asynctask i can put it like :

```
 class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Task Completed.";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txt.setText(result);
            btn.setText("Restart");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        txt.setText("Task Starting...");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        txt.setText("Running..."+ values[0]);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
```

But with getMapAsync i can't:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
  this.map = map;
  map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Please save my day. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you could just show it when you call getMapAsync() and hide it in onMapReady().  You can't get the progress though.

Comment: i will try this, but nothing show :(

Comment: It should be really fast, that's probably why it's not showing.  Why exactly do you want to show a progress bar here?

Comment: When i using getMapAsync , it delay(white screen)  but not show progressbar.This is problem. :(